# Dynamically 'reflect' database value to the UIView elements

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uiview, uibutton

I have an UIScrollView which contains series of UIView. Each UIView contains UIImageView and several UIButtons. These UIViews represent 'book' and their data are stored in sqlite database.

BookCover class:

```
// Cover
_coverImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(SHELF_CELL_PADDING_X, SHELF_CELL_PADDING_Y, SHELF_CELL_COVER_WIDTH, SHELF_CELL_COVER_HEIGHT)];
[self addSubview:_coverImageView];

// Label
_coverTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(SHELF_CELL_PADDING_X, SHELF_CELL_COVER_HEIGHT, SHELF_CELL_TITLE_WIDTH, SHELF_CELL_TITLE_HEIGHT)];
_coverTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_coverTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
_coverTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
_coverTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
//_coverTitle.font = [_coverTitle.font fontWithSize:10];
_coverTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:10];
[self addSubview:_coverTitle];

// New Label
_labelNew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 6)];
[self addSubview:_labelNew];

// Favourite Button
_favouriteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
_favouriteButton.frame = CGRectMake(SHELF_CELL_COVER_WIDTH - 5, -5, 23, 23);
[_favouriteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favouriteButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self addSubview:_favouriteButton];

// Download Button
_downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
_downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(SHELF_CELL_COVER_WIDTH - 5, SHELF_CELL_COVER_HEIGHT - 20, 23, 23);
[_downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self addSubview:_downloadButton];
```

And in the 'book list view', I just set actual data to each UIView(BookCover) something like this:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, SHELF_SEARCH_HEIGHT + SHELF_SECTION_HEIGHT + SHELF_HEIGHT + SHELF_SECTION_HEIGHT + 5, self.view.frame.size.width, SHELF_HEIGHT)];
NSUInteger BookCoverCount = [pamphletList count];
for (int i=0; i<BookCoverCount; i++) {
    CGFloat coverX = i * 100;

    BookCover *bookCover = [[BookCoverView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(coverX, 10, SHELF_CELL_WIDTH, SHELF_CELL_HEIGHT)];
    bookCover.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Set an image for cover...
    NSDictionary *bookData = [bookList objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *bookId = [bookData objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *bookImageName = [bookData objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSString *bookImageDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", documentDir, BOOK_FOLDER, bookId];
    UIImage *bookImageFile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bookImageDir, bookImageName]];
    bookCover.coverImageView.image = bookImageFile;
    bookCover.coverTitle.text = [bookData objectForKey:@"title"];
    bookCover.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    bookCover.tag = i;

    [scrollView addSubview:bookCover];
}
```

I need to change 'Favourite Button' and 'Download Button' images and run the sql like "UPDATE book SET is_favourite = 1 WHERE book_id = x" every time the user touches them.

How should I implement those, and when should I run the sql to reflect the user's action to the 'book' object? I have already set up database and have a class to handle the sql. And again I feel so stupid to ask a question like this. But as an objective-c beginner, the advices from the professionals here is huge help to me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I did it with most simplest way:

```
- (void) favouriteButtonTouched:(id)sender 
{
   UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
   int bookId = clickedButton.tag;

   [db openDB];
   NSDictionary *bookData = [db getBookById:bookId];
   if (bookData != nil) 
   {
       if ([[bookData objectForKey:@"is_fav"] integerValue] == 0) {
           [_favouriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [db setFavouriteForId:bookId setValue:1];
       } 
       else 
       {
           [_favouriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_empty.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [db setFavouriteForId:bookId setValue:0];
       }
   }
   [db closeDB];

}
```

I still don't know if this is a good practice to change UIView elements (UIButton in this case), call DB operations dynamically each time the button is pressed. But anyway this is my solution for now...